# MAMP and joomla related query

Tags: joomla, mamp

I had installed MAMP on my Macbook but i forgot the password. How to create new installation of MAMP. I dont mind deleting the database.

How to integrate joomla with MAMP?

Which are the best bulletein boards for joomla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this tutorial to setup a local server on your machine http://www.joomlatraining.com/newsletters/install-joomla-on-a-mac/

Try this bulletin board for Joomla http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/forum/3438.
There are a number of other ones but I suggest that you investigate which one is good for you.  Start looking here http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/forum